# Update from .NET 3.1 to .NET 6,app not working as before

Tags: angular, .net-core, .net-6.0, angular13

I recently migrated an Angular 13 +.NET Core 3.1 app to .Net 6, I've changed target framework from 3.1 to 6, updated all packages to v6, no changes in code (front or back).

On Vps I've uninstalled net core hosting bundle 3.1 and installed v6+restart.

Since the upgrade very often,on start,app remains in loading screen with no error in console,no request in network tab, If I reloaded it the works and I can see requests in network tab.

If I revert back to Net 3.1 and there is no problem,same issue in.NET 5

Comment: Do you have logs? Any info there?

Comment: no,how to get logs?